# ChartBoost negative balance

Tags: chartboost

Today we launched our first campaign on Chartboost. We added 300$ on account and started our first campaign. In less than one our we spent all the money. Then I switched campaign off but still the balance going up in negative. Can you help me why? Beacuse we didn't pay for that additional negative balance we made campaign for 290$ not 450$ ...

What can we do?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for campaigns to go over budget is the fact that they reach their budget in the minutes before the first check that compares the spend to the budget. This can happen if you your campaign has a wide target (ie - if you are targeting the whole world for example). Campaigns that have very broad targeting (little to no usage of filtering or available targeting on the dashboard) will serve impressions very quickly and this only increases the probability of exceeding the budget.

It is also very common for CPI campaigns to continue to "Spend Money" even after the campaign has been turned off. The reason why this happens is that we attribute installs to recorded clicks up to 21 days after the click. Also, the Install is not recorded until the 1st bootup of the app. For a number of reasons this 1st bootup may not occur until a couple of days after downloading onto the device from the App Store. There is no way to "turn off installs" for clicks that have already occurred.

Hope this helps.